# C - pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code:

```
int strlen(char *s){
    char *p = s;

    while(*p++ != '\0');

    return p - s;
}
```

Why does the above evaluate differently than this:

```
int strlen(char *s){
    char *p = s;

    while(*p != '\0') p++;

    return p - s;
}
```

It is my understanding that the expression will evaluate first, and then increment.

Comment: Do you understand that there's a difference between `i++` and `++i`?

Comment: Both increment the variable by 1, and result in the same answer if not in an expression. I can correctly use the the two in practice, but it just appeared to me that similar use with pointers yielded different results. As in: if(i++ > 5), the original value of i would be used, and incremented after the evaluation.

Comment: Because there's a difference between the two, but it's nothing to do with pointers.  Try `int i = 3, j = 3;  printf("%d, %d\n", ++i, j++);`.

Comment: I know, but the same concept when used on pointers does not seems to yield similar results. As in the use of *(++ptr), and *(ptr++). My question was, shouldn't the expression internal to the parenthesis be evaluated first since they have the highest precedence? If this is not the case, then it makes sense otherwise.

Comment: I just thought that, by use of the expression *(ptr++), than it would evaluate to the ptr++ first, and then dereference it. But it appears that I have assumed incorrectly.

Comment: It *does* get evaluated first.  `*(ptr++)` is equivalent to `char *tmp = ptr++; *tmp`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: I edited the OP. But I was not getting results that agree with what you say. *(ptr++) and *(++ptr) were evaluating differently for me when I was trying it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Surely the difference between `i++` and `++i` is irrelevant to this question?

Comment: @Henrik: The OP has *completely* rewritten the question since I posted my comments...

Comment: @Henrik I edited the OP because it was originally much more complicated and unnecessary. I edited and pasted in the specific code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah, would you look at that! Read the unedited post, your comment makes much more sense now.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth  I have readdressed the concerns in a more concise way with example output here. Please check it out. [Revised Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636969/c-pointers-and-different-results)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the first code `p` is incremented regardless of if the `while()` condition was true or false.

In the second snippet of code, `p` is incremented ONLY if `while` condition was true.

Comment: Bhai **:** first can be rectified as  `while(*p++); return (p- s -1);`

Comment: Surely bhai @GrijeshChauhan

Answer (score 2):

Consider the last step in while loop when `*p = '\0'`.

In 1<sup>st</sup> code:

```
while(*p++ != '\0');
```

`p` still get one increment, and pointer to the element behind `'\0'`.

In 2<sup>nd</sup> code:

```
while(*p != '\0') p++;
```

`*p != '\0'` is not true, so while loop end, p get no increment. `p` pointer to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case:-

```
while(*p++ != '\0');
```

p will be incremented just after the evaluation of an expression irrespective of whether the condition is true or false because `++` is a part of conditional expression.

Whereas, in the second one:-

```
while(*p != '\0') p++;
```

First the condition will be checked and if it is true then only  p will be incremented.

Comment: No, I think the comparison happens before the increment in **both** cases. `++p` would do the increment before the comparison. But in the first case, the increment is executed even if the string is zero length.

Comment: @Sanjay, Oh... yes actually the increment will take place just after the condition is checked. No matter whether its true or false(First Case) . I forgot that's a post increment. ;)

Comment: the condition is first checked if `*p` contains `\0` or not. If it does, `p++` is incremented in the second snippet. Whereas, `p` will be incremented regardless of if the condition where true or false in the first snippet.